# Merge fields not populating in email template

Tags: email-template, merge-field

I created a classic email template and have merged fields from a custom object called Order (not the native Salesforce Order object).

The following merged fields don't seem to work:

Order Name:  {!NU__Order__c.Name}
Pay NOW URL:  {!NU__Order__c.PayNowUrl__c}
Payment URL:  {!NU__Order__c.NU__PaymentUrl__c}

However, oddly enough this one works:

Balance: {!NU__Order__c.NU__Balance__c}

And this one works - {!Order.Name} -  even though we aren't using the standard Order object.

All the above fields on the Order record are populated.

I even tried fields on a related object (Cart):

TEST: {!NU__Cart__c.NU__PaymentUrl__c}
TEST: {!NU__Cart__c.PayNowUrl__c}

Thanks in advance for any help. Looking through some help docs but have not found any solution yet.

Regards,
Wil

Comment: Can you share more of your template? A key part of this will be the attributes in your `messaging:emailTemplate` tag.

Comment: How are you calling this template?  Email Alert or Apex or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your email is being triggered from some object where there is not an "NU__Order__c" record in context.

When you say "balance__c" works and "order.name" works - how do you know they work?  If you don't use the standard order object, it would have no name, and you wouldn't see anything on the template.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the custom object (Order) is named exactly like the native Order object which prevented the merged fields to be displayed.